# Can access_token generated by YouTube API help to play a private video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

A person has some private YouTube videos and he does not want the videos to be directly shared with any other user. If he generates an access_token with YouTube API using his credentials, can the access_token be anyway used to play the videos by other user ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set access token, but if the user makes the videos unlisted, it will still be unshared ut since only user would know the ids, he can watch with iframe API.

If user doesn't know the ids, he can list with Data API using the token.